# Retrieving JavaScript's eventObject when using Google Maps API listener

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps, firefox, google-maps-api-3

In google maps API V3, I would like to add a marker to the map if the user control-clicked the map.
For that, I've added a listener to the map, as follows -

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e){
if (event.ctrlKey)
    add_marker(e.position);
});
```

The *e* parameter, passed by the listener, contains some data, but mostly regarding the position of the click, while I want to be able to ask if the control button was pressed during the time the usser clicked on the map.

I found that chrome had an object *event*, which is the default Javascript's eventObject, that contained the data I needed (ctrlKey) and this indeed works in chrome.

However, when I tried the same code in FF, it couldn't find an object called 'event', and I can't find a way to retrieve it.

I would appreciate your help in finding a solution that will work on IE too.

Thank,
DanC

Answer (score 1):

The API doesn't say anything about accessing the DOM-event-object.

The argument passed to the callback-function currently contains a property **`b`** which refers to the event-object, so you could use **`e.b.ctrlKey`**

But as this is not documented it's not reliable may change tomorrow.

**Another option:**
You may observe the event for the div that contains the map without using the API-method:

```
map.getDiv().onclick=function(e)
{
  e=window.event||e;
  if (e.ctrlKey)
  {
    //do something
  }
}
```

Comment: The e.b doen't exist for me (which strengthens your point of not using an undocumented property..). Regarding the other method of capturing the event - this does give me the eventObject, but takes away the API one, which I need for the position of the click (to create a marker there).